# I want to use _msize alternative but I don't know

Tags: c

First of all, I am practicing C language in VScode on m2 Mac.
I want to use `_msize` like got used it on Windows.
I tried to use the alternative `malloc_usable_size()` that I found.
When I use it, it fails.

My native language is Korean. Please excuse my English.

I want to know the allocated buffer size. I want to use something like `msize` on Windows.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code. Also, state what you want your code to do. Also, what happens instead of your desired behavior? You wrote "somethings error"; this is not enough to understand and fix the error. Post your error and describe which tool outputs it.

Comment: ```malloc_usable_size()``` is supposed to be used for debugging purposes only: the size it returns might be larger than the one you are actually supposed to use in the program. See [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html). If you use ```malloc``` to allocate memory, you should already know the size of the block you are allocating. Could you provide an example of code that showcases the use of ```_msize``` you have in mind?

Comment: Under "7.22.3 Memory management functions", the C11 standard only mentions `aligned_alloc`, `calloc`, `malloc`, and `realloc`. There doesn't seem to be a portable way to retrieve the size of the object created by memory allocator. There is not a widely available alternative.